# optimised query for default value in informix

Tags: optimization, view, informix, default-value

Requirement: To create a view in which records come from 4 tables 
First field come from scr, secount from mxr, 3rd is default fourth from mrt..

fifth is desc which is language based..and the condition is as follows
there is a field lng in mxr w need to read rpr with the help of data_el_nm and lng(of mxr) if no record found then read rpr with the help of data_el_nm and lng(of scr) if not found read with data_el_nm and default lng(which is en).. UNTILL this is handled if all three is not found make the field with spaces. i made that by putting outer across rpr but it is taking to much time. can any one sugest optimised way to do this? Thank u

```
CREATE VIEW "informix".abc(
cmpy_id,
lgn_id,
fld_nm,
data_el_nm,
desc
)

AS

SELECT

s.cmpy_id,
u.lgn_id,
"RTONM",
r.rto_nm,
rcs_0.long_cptn_var

FROM

scr s,
mxr u,
mrt r,
outer(rpr rcs_0)

WHERE

rcs_0.data_el_nm = r.rto_nm AND
(rcs_0.lng = u.lng OR (NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_1
where rcs_1.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_1.lng = u.lng)
AND rcs_0.lng = s.bas_lng) OR (NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_2
where rcs_2.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_2.lng = u.lng)
AND NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_3 where
rcs_3.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_3.lng = s.bas_lng)
AND rcs_0.lng = 'en'))

UNION ALL
SELECT

s.cmpy_id,
u.lgn_id,
"RTONM",
r.rto_nm,
rcs_0.long_cptn_var

FROM

scr s,
mxr u,
mrt r,
outer(rpr rcs_0)

WHERE

rcs_0.data_el_nm = r.rto_nm AND
(rcs_0.lng = u.lng OR (NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_1
where rcs_1.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_1.lng = u.lng)
AND rcs_0.lng = s.bas_lng) OR (NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_2
where rcs_2.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_2.lng = u.lng)
AND NOT EXISTS(select * from rpr rcs_3 where
rcs_3.rc_id = rcs_0.rc_id AND rcs_3.lng = s.bas_lng)
AND rcs_0.lng = 'en'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to read your queries or the explanatory text that goes with them, and I cannot see what the purpose of the `UNION ALL` is, since the queries either side appear identical. In any case I would suggest you probably want to explore using regular joins with a nested `NVL()`, or perhaps a `CASE` or `DECODE()` statement.

```
CREATE VIEW "informix".abc
(
    cmpy_id,
    lgn_id,
    fld_nm,
    data_el_nm,
    desc
)

AS
SELECT
    s.cmpy_id,
    u.lgn_id,
    "RTONM",
    r.rto_nm,
    NVL(mxr_lng.long_cptn_var, NVL(scr_lng.long_cptn_var, NVL(def_lng.long_cptn_var, ' ')))
FROM
    scr AS s,
    mxr AS u,
    mrt AS r,
    outer rpr AS mxr_lng,
    outer rpr AS scr_lng,
    outer rpr AS def_lng
WHERE mxr_lng.data_el_nm = r.rto_nm AND mxr_lng.lng = u.lng
  AND scr_lng.data_el_nm = r.rto_nm AND scr_lng.lng = s.bas_lng
  AND def_lng.data_el_nm = r.rto_nm AND def_lng.lng = 'en'
```

The nested `NVL()` calls will take the `long_cptn_var` from mxr first, but if that is NULL then scr, if that's NULL then the default, otherwise a space.

Obviously I cannot test this code, but it should give you the general idea even if it's not syntactically perfect.

Comment: thanks..i found another way..i made a function which will give value to caption variable..this made query run very fast..

Thank u for ur time..